# adding a New column and add the rows to the newly created column

Tags: r

I have a 100x20 matrix now I want to add a new column and I have to do the sum of the twenty columns. I am trying to find a function to do this, can any one help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vector that is sum of rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991905/vector-that-is-sum-of-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a new column to the matrix, with values that are the sum of the existing columns?

Given your matrix in `m`, this should do it:

```
newcol <- sapply(1:nrow(m), function(row) { sum(m[row,]) })
m <- cbind(m, newcol)
```

**UPDATE**

I didn't know `rowSums`! As [@Rfan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2862090/rfan) pointed out, this could be simplified to:

```
m <- cbind(m, rowSums(m))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `rowSums`.
if your data is m

```
m <- matrix(rexp(2000, rate=.1), ncol=20)
#creating totals
mtotal <- rowSums(m)
#adding totals to the matrix    
m <- cbind(m,mtotal)
```