# sum across columns within rows for all columns that start with a specific character string in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a set of species IDs in the `ID` column, and sample IDs as separate columns with the motif `CA_**`. The data look like this:

```
ID    <- c('A','B','C')
CA_01 <- c(3,9,54)
CA_56 <- c(2,7,12)
CA_92 <- c(45,4,47)
d<- data.frame(ID,CA_01,CA_56,CA_92)

 ID CA_01 CA_56 CA_92
  A     3     2    45
  B     9     7     4
  C    54    12    47
```

I want to sum across the columns within each row, and generate a new column, that is the total abundance of each species ID across sample columns (final values 50, 20, 113). Furthermore, There are many other columns in my real data frame. I only want  to sum across columns that start with `CA_**`.

NOTE: this is different than the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991905/sum-rows-in-data-frame-or-matrix), as the asker knows the positions of the columns the asker wants to sum. Imy example I only know that the columns start with the motif, `CA_`. I don't know the positions. Its also different that the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587334/subset-data-to-contain-only-columns-whose-names-match-a-condition), as I specifically ask how to sum across columns based on the `grep` command.

Comment: Have you looked at any tutorials or tried anything yet?

Comment: @PierreLafortune the example you say this is a duplicate of knows exactly which rows the asker wants to sum. I do not in this case, making my solution, and the question, different. can you please unmark duplicate?

Comment: [subset data to contain only columns whose names match a condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587334/subset-data-to-contain-only-columns-whose-names-match-a-condition)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `grep` to subset the columns having column names that start with `CA_` and get the sum of the rows with `rowSums`.

```
d$newCol <- rowSums(d[grep('^CA\\_', names(d))])
```