# Display sum after each row r

Tags: r

```
df <- as_tibble(a <- c(1,2,3))
df
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  value
  <dbl>
1     1
2     2
3     3
```

The goal is this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  value   Sum
  <dbl>   
1     1   1
2     2   3
3     3   6
```

So just display the sum after each row. 1 = 1. 1+2 = 3. 3+3 = 6, and so on. I guess it's kinda easy, maybe with rowSums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a cumulative sum.  In `R`, there is `cumsum` to do that

```
df$Sum <- cumsum(df$value)
```

We could do the same while constructing the 'tibble

```
library(tibble)
df <- tibble(value = 1:3, Sum = cumsum(value))
```

Comment: Thanks. I googled it for a while but couldn't find this function. I guess i just used the wrong words?

Comment: @Dutschke with google, if you don't use the right key words, it may take time to get to exact page

Comment: @Dutschke May be you queried `sum after each row` that can yield a different response i.e. for me, the first page showed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991905/sum-rows-in-data-frame-or-matrix) i.e. it parsed as row sums

Comment: That's exactly what i did in some variations... cumulative would have been the key word.